# Selectively omit portions of QGraphicsScene displayed by QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicspixmapitem

Let's say I have a single `QGraphicsScene` which contains a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. I want to render this scene in two separate locations on the screen, via two separate `QGraphicsView`s, but in different ways:

1. A small view of the entire image (like a minimap)
2. A *partial* view of the image (i.e., only a selected area)

This partial view is not just a zoomed-in view (`setSceneRect()` isn't the solution). It is a view showing only parts of the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` that a user has selected: if in the minimap view I choose some block of pixels in the middle of the image, then on the partial view it will show just those pixels and I can zoom/pan/etc. without seeing anything else.

In the following image, you can see in the minimap the selected part of the image highlighted in red, and in the larger view, only that selected portion of the image:

[image: Selective rendering example]

Solving this problem via `QGraphicsScene` is trivial, which is how this is implemented in the example above. However, I want to solve this problem strictly via `QGraphicsView` if possible, as I'm trying to stick to a very strict MVC framework with a minimal number of data copies/versions/representations.

If that's not possible, then I will resort to using two scenes, which is less than ideal

Comment: QGraphicsView doesn't allow "selective" painting by default. Items, on the other hand, can theoretically "detect" the view in which they're painted: the last `widget` argument of the `paint()` function called for all items corresponds to the view's viewport, so you could clip the painter to a specific portion before calling the base `paint()` method (just remember to `save/restore` the painter before and after all this). That said, I see that the editing portion is quite small, so you may consider other alternatives for it: use a completely separated item constructed from the portion of the »

Comment: » original image, and send changes made to it to the "minimap" scene or item using a custom signal with the coordinates of the pixel and their new color, that will be eventually applied to the source image, considering the origin point of the current selection. This approach would be more scalable and could even provide a multi-level undo/redo stack for the editing.